# SF short story about sleepers living other peoples lives

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In my early teens I read loads of Sci-Fi. I'm looking for a short story. All I can remember  is this: It was about several people kept alive by life support machines; they could choose different "lives" to live.

The story starts with the death of a farmer, on his death the Sleeper awakes and looks around the room at the others an at the machine keeping him alive and wonders how long he's been there.....
Sorry not that much to go on :)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Roughly speaking, when were you in your teens? Do you recall if you read this in a magazine or anthology?

Comment: Hi Yess......  sorry...... a date might have helped!

Comment: It was an anthology and It would have been mid 1970's in Perth Australia